# mediation in multilevel model with binary mediator and outcome

Tags: r

I want to use the bmlm for mediation analysis.

It has a solution for binary outcome (Y) butI didn't find information regarding binary mediator.

Can I use this package when both mediator and outcome are binary variables?

Answer (score 0):

Look into mediation or medflex packages. They allow you to specify a model for mediator and the outcome.